# What is blocking this Nginx site on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have recently signed up for the Amazon Web Service Free Tier and started an EC2 instance.  I installed Nginx on this server and started the service.  The problem is that whenever I try to  navigate to the public DNS provided by Amazon's EC2 Management Console, I receive "This page can't be displayed".

I have added a new security group within the EC2 Management Console providing access to port 80, 22, and 443 (to 0.0.0.0/0).

I have verified nginx is running by

> ps -ef | grep nginx

and it returned

[image]

I verified it is listening on port 80 by running

```
netstat -pant | grep :80
```

and it returned

[image]

I verified the default site is enabled in the .conf file and contains the "Welcome to Nginx" message.

Any ideas what could be blocking the site?

Comment: what does `telnet ec2_instance_public_hostname 80` tell you ? Run the telnet command from the same box where you are trying to open the NginX page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did not need to create a new security group.  I had to edit an existing one, opening the HTTP port.  I'm not sure what the security group I created did, but it's gone now.